# Merging GIF with PNG file

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, gm

I want to combine 4 image into one, 2 GIF and 2 PNG. I'm doing this with graphic image but unfortunately the plugin is picking up the first frame of GIF only. The end result is a tile of 4 standstill image. Is there any method I missed out from graphic magic? I got the gif file now but the 2 gif is not animating as expected.

Is there any other plugin can achieve the merging with animation?

Comment: How about sharing the images?

Comment: You mean you need the images? @MarkSetchell

Comment: Yes, it's kind of hard to merge images I haven't got :-)